# How is this symbol equivalent to 11?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

My Physics teacher recently showed our class one of his old math clocks, where all of the numbers are little math puzzles. The entire class, including our teacher was stumped by the symbol for 11. Can anyone explain how that symbol/expression is equivalent to 11?

[Zoomed Out View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqtNj.jpg)

[Zoomed In View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxuSF.jpg)

Comment: That's just a weird font. In a number system with base greater than eleven, "a" is used for ten and "b" is used to denote eleven. Think about hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: It's hexadecimal. The bold $0$ is used instead of the more familiar prefix $0x$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField It would be helpful to post that as an answer so this question no longer appears as available for answering.

Answer (score 2):

This is hexadecimal where they're using the prefix $\mathbb{0}$ instead of the more familiar $0x$ which gives us $\mathbb{0}b=11$.